# Proof by induction: $(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}a^{n-2}b^2+...+nab^{n-1}+b^n$

Tags: analysis, induction

I'm studying in preparation for a Mathematical Analysis I examination and I'm solving past exam exercises.
*If it's any indicator of difficulty, the exercise is Exercise 1 of 4, part $a$ and graded for 8%, so it's supposed to be pretty easy.*

> Use induction to prove that $(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}a^{n-2}b^2+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}a^{n-3}b^3+...+nab^{n-1}+b^n$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

I've got the three steps in mind, but I'm failing at the third.

It's obviously true for n=1: $(a+b)^1=a^1+1a^0b$

Let it be true for n=k: $(a+b)^k=a^k+ka^{n
k-1}b+\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2!}a^{k-2}b^2+\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}a^{k-3}b^3+...+kab^{k-1}+b^k$
The third step is obviously the problematic one for me. By expanding the formula for n=k+1, I fail to produce something recognisable that will lead me to something valid like $(a+b)(a+b)^k$

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In the third step, try multiplying the RHS of what you got in the second step with $(a+b)$.

That will create two distinct series of sums, say $S_1$ and $S_2$, where
$$S_1=a(a^k+ka^{k-1}b+\cdots+kab^{k-1}+b^k)=a^{k+1}+ka^kb+\cdots+ka^2b^{k-1}+ab^k$$
$$S_2=b(a^k+ka^{k-1}b+\cdots+kab^{k-1}+b^k)=a^kb+ka^{k-1}b^2+\cdots+kab^k+b^{k+1}$$
If you leave out the first term in $S_1$ and last term in $S_2$, then its just a matter of using
$${x \choose y}+{x \choose y-1}={x+1 \choose y}$$
which can be easily proved.

Comment: RHS? Not a native English speaker, sorry.

Comment: @Dimitris RHS = right hand side

Comment: There's a small typo in your answer, at $S_2$, you've missed a $b^2$. I've laid out $S_1$ and $S_2$ and left out $a^{k+1}$ and $b^{k+1}$ but still, how is the middle part helping and how is it related to the choose functions you mentioned?

Comment: If you see the coefficients for $a^{k-i+1}b^i$, they are ${k \choose i}$ in $S_1$ and ${k \choose i-1}$ in $S_2$. Adding them with the rule I mentioned proves the induction.

Answer (score 0):

This is just binomial theorem!

See inductive proof in this wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem